# vector data in jlist?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to display the data in vector in jlist. The below method `connect()`executes fine, without any error when it is called, but the vector data is not displayed in jlist. My code is:

```java
public void connect(String user, String pass)
{
    vdate = new Vector(); 
    vsubject = new Vector();
    vfrom = new Vector();
    vmessage = new Vector(); 

    final String password = pass;
    final String username = user;

    try
    {

        props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");

        session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                    }
                });

        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect();
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) 
        {  
            Message message = messages[i];
            Address[] from = message.getFrom();
            frm = from[0].toString();
            vfrom.addElement(frm);
            date = message.getSentDate().toString();
            vdate.addElement(date);
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)message.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            mess = ""+bp.getContent();
            subject = message.getSubject().toString();
            vsubject.addElement(subject);
        }

        jList1.setListData(vdate);
        jList2.setListData(vsubject);
        jList3.setListData(vfrom);
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The for loop executes fine. Also the data gets stored in vector but when I set it to jlist nothing shows up........plz help

Comment: Maybe you should point out exactly what data in the vector you want displayed and how you want it displayed. What you are currently doing is trying to placed three difference vector in the list. But each call to `setListData()` overwrites the previous. So you may need to explain to us exactly what you are trying to achieve with this. For instance, did you just want all the data from each vector place one after the the next? Or is the data from each vector in parralel to each other and you want to place say parallel indices into one item in the list? Please clarify what you wish to accomplish

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1):

```
jList1.setListData(vdate);
jList1.setListData(vsubject);
jList1.setListData(vfrom);
```

Every time you invoke the `setListData(...)` method the data in the JList get replaced. So the best case scenario is that you will get the data in the vFrom Vector.

Just use a single Vector for all the data.

Comment: sorry mate,I posted the wrong code.
jList1.setListData(vdate);
jList1.setListData(vsubject);
jList1.setListData(vfrom);

 I've edited it. You can take a look now...sorry again......